# How to package my React hook effects for others to re-use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm want to create several open-source React effects for react hooks. For e.g., an effect that checks and updates the user token balance.

The question is: How to pack the `effect` and create a module, so it will be easy for others to use? How are they going to import and use the effect?

There is any best-practice for that?

Comment: `an effect that checks and updates the user token balance.` how would this use case help in open source

Answer (score 2):

Your hook must be build with the "low level" [hooks provided by react](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html). Coming up with a reusable/generic authentication hook might be challenging though.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
const useAuthentication = () => {
  const [user] = useState({}) // maybe shape of user.name, user.avatar, user.email ?
  useEffect(() => {
    // whatever
  })
  ...
  const login = ...
  const logout = ...
  return [user, login, logout]
}
export default useAuthentication


// a user of this hook
import useAuthentication from 'my-published-authentication-hook'
const Header = () => {
  [user, login, logout] = useAuthentication()
  return (
    // whatever login/logout button, user name, etc
  )
}
```